# Is this the best way to traverse an array in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've been doing searches like this for awhile, and I feel there is probably a better way of doing this. The situation is I have a double elimination tournament bracket and have to find one of the games. The winners and losers brackets are stored in an array, and then games are stored within each of those arrays.

The structure looks like this

```
{
   tournament: {
       brackets: [

           {games: [{id:'x'},{id:'y'},...,{id:'z'}]},
           {games: [{id:'x'},{id:'y'},...,{id:'z'}]}
           ]
       ]
   }
}
```

This is the code I'm using to find an ID.

```
for (var i = 0; i < tournament.brackets.length; i++) {
 for (var y = 0; y < tournament.brackets[i].games;length; y++) {
    // Does the ID of this object match known ID    
 }
}
```

Comment: `brackets` is not a valid array. Are its elements `games: ...` the objects? Like this: `brackets: [ { games: ...} ]` ? Or `brackets` is an object in the reality, and looks like `brackets: { games: [] }` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "*have to find one of the games*"? What info from the game do you return? Usually the better idea is to change the data structure, not the code syntax.

Comment: Derp. yeah its like `brackets: [ { games: ...} ]` I'll update thanks @wostex

Comment: looking to get a score int inside a particular game object. And I would change the data but the end point I call to only returns this @Bergi :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question ES6, there's indeed a better way to do this:

```
for (var bracket of tournament.brackets) {
  for (var game of bracket.games) {
    // Does the ID of this object match known ID    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple alternative (if you are searching often) would be to build a reverse lookup array based on the game id.  Something like:

```
var lookup = {};
for (var i = 0; i < tournament.brackets.length; i++) {
 for (var y = 0; y < tournament.brackets[i].games.length; y++) {
    lookup[tournament.brackets[i].games[y].id] = { bracket: i, game: y };
 }
}
```

Then later:

```
function findGame( id, lookup, tournament ) {
    if ( !lookup.hasOwnProperty( id ) )
        return false;

    var location = lookup[id];
    return tournament.brackets[location.bracket].games[location.game];
}
```

Comment: I don't see where that would be a problem.  In the first block of code I am generating the lookup object and creating keys in it.  As a result, id is definitely not in lookup but that is the point.

In the second block of code I am searching in lookup and specifically handling the case where id isn't in lookup.  I'm afraid you're going to have to be more specific for me to follow your point.

Comment: The question is tagged [tag:es6], so why not use a proper `Map`?

Comment: I didn't notice the es6 tag.  I just assumed vanilla javascript.  That being said, map is not particularly helpful here because it returns another array.  I want a lookup table, and objects are ideally for that (it is pretty much what they are made for after all).

Comment: `Map`s are better suited as lookup tables than objects, actually. But what do you mean by "it returns another array"?

Comment: Oops, nevermind.  I thought you were referring to the map function on arrays, i.e. using a map function to somehow flatten the two dimensional array to a simple lookup table instead of a double for loop.  I was definitely on the wrong page, lol!